# How to generate numbers list starting from 3

Tags: php

I have this PHP code 
What this code do is matching month count to numbers .
If condition is true echo result!
Result is displayed in table for each user.
$isT is count of months between 2 dates example 1,2,3 or 9

```
    if($isT=='3' 
OR $isT=='6' 
OR $isT=='9' 
OR $isT=='12' 
OR $isT=='15' 
OR $isT=='18' 
OR $isT=='21'){
   //echo something
}
```

What i want is make this numbers automatically generated

So it would be like:

```
    if($isT==$generatednumber[$i]){
   //echo something
}
```

i need numbers in this order 3 6 9 12 15. ..

basically +3 to the last number

Comment: `if(($isT % 3) == 0)){//echo something}`. I think you want this

Comment: Anant is right. Check the documentation, someone have a brief explanation of the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.arithmetic.php#70424)

Comment: OMG you guys are right , i was trying so many things and wasting my time!!! Thanks :)

Comment: I lerned something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said modulus (%) is needed here:-

```
if(!empty($isT) && ($isT % 3) == 0)){

//echo something

}
```

Note:- this code will check:-

1.Your variable is set

2.Have some value

3.Is a multiple of 3.

Comment: does the OP want negative values? I don't think so.

Comment: @SunilBN  he started his code with positive digit(dates)

Comment: oh yeah, its dates :D

Comment: as your numbers are multiple of 3(3,6,9,12,18...), so modulus(%) will check that your current generated number is a multiple of 3 or not and then work accordingly.thanks

Answer (score 2):

First make sure its more than 0 then check if its multiple of 3.

```
if($isT >0 && ($isT % 3) == 0)){
    //echo something
}
```

Comment: Your answer also is good but as Anant comented about it i will pick his answer :) Thanks